# Getting MultiValueDictError in fetch POST data django

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, django, django-views

I am trying to fetch GET data receiving from an HTML form.

But it is giving me MultiValueDictError.
It is also saying

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

My HTML code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="home_redirect/fd" id="redirect" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" value={{user}} name="user">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("redirect").submit()
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My views.py :

```
def home(request):
    user = request.POST['user']
    return render(request, 'main.html', {'login': user})
```

Comment: The `method="post"`, so the data is in `request.POST` (the payload of the request).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you html i remove `action` and script. Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form  id="redirect" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" value={{user}} name="user">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here we checking the method is `POST` then `redirect` to your `url`.

```
def home(request):
    user = request.POST
    if request.method =="POST":
        return redirect('home_redirect') # home_redirect is the redirected url
    return render(request, 'afl_announcement/main.html', {'login': user})
```

Comment: what is the url name of redirect??  `return redirect('url_name')` from this, `url_name` is the name of the redirect url

Comment: This Reference may helpfull you : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render . When click a submit button to  home function get request if you will not redirect in the form.

Comment: `return redirect('https://www.google.com/')`  to easily experiment with redirect to Google

Answer (score 0):

In your `<form>` you specify:

```
<form action="home_redirect/fd" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" value={{user}} name="user">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

so you make a POST request, and the data is encoded in the *payload* of the request. You access this data through `request.POST`:

```
def home(request):
    user = request.POST['user']
    return render(request, 'main.html', {'login': user})
```

Comment: I made the changes you told but it still didn't work.